# Cкролл при динамическом добавлении большого количества элементов C#(winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Добавляю блок нескольких контролов в tablelayout,который расположен на tabpage динамически при нажатии на кнопку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при добавлении большого количества блоков форма выглядит некорректно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хочу добавить скролл, чтобы можно было разместить все элементы.Выставить autoscroll в свойствах не помогло.Как это реализовать?

Comment: Еще раз, объедините элементы блоков с помощью UserControl и добавляйте готовые контролы в  FlowLayoutPanel, а саму FLP положите в TabPage и будет вам нормальный скролл "из коробки". Не так что-бы слишком много действий, зато логика будет простая и прозрачная.

Comment: Я как-то пробовал с FLP, но плохо работает при ресайзе, длина меняется,но не меняются отступы между текстбоксами и т.п. мб ещё найду чего с ней

Comment: @rdorn а мы можем пойти в чат? Чтобы уже все точки над и расставить))) Меня только разметка эта беспокоит, остальное вроде я сделал и не буду больше терроризировать стаковерфлоу)

Comment: К сожалению, у меня нет возможности создать чат к вопросу. Я просто ни как не могу понять, какого конечного результата вы хотите добиться. Ну и попробуйте в текущем варианте выставить не только относительные, но и абсолютные минимальные размеры. Масштабирование под размер экрана или окна можно делать по-разному.

Comment: Я хочу динамически добавлять блок по кнопке, как это делать понятно. Если использовать FLP, то при изменении размеров контролы внутри не адаптируются(ваще FLP вижу как какое-то извращение). А в tablelayout всё автоматически в процентах поставил и идеально при увеличении/уменьшении размера работает. Если уж для скролла надо FLP, то мне интересно, как её нормально настроить(а то окно увеличилось, а все контролы остались в верхней части экрана...) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ставим нашему TableLayoutPanel следующие свойства :

Dock = DockStyle.Top(любой подойдет)

AutoSize = true

AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink

AutoScroll = false.

Вставляем наш TableLayoutPanel в Panel с свойствами :

Dock = DockStyle.Fill(так же любой)

AutoScroll = true

AutoSize = false.

Answer (score 2):

[image: пример работы]

Добавляем Panel, а в нее уже вставляем кнопку и текстбокс

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //последний текстбокс
        var lastTb = _panel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Last();

        //замораживаем отрисовку интерфейса
        this.SuspendLayout();

        //устанавливаем свойства для нового исходя из предыдущей
        int vDelta = lastTb.Height + 4; 
        var newTb = new TextBox();
        newTb.Location = new Point(lastTb.Location.X,
            lastTb.Location.Y + vDelta);

        newTb.Height = lastTb.Height;
        newTb.Width = lastTb.Width;

        //добавляем в панель новый текстбокс
        _panel.Controls.Add(newTb);

        //сдвигаем кнопку
        _buttonAdd.Location = new Point(_buttonAdd.Location.X,
            _buttonAdd.Location.Y + vDelta);

        //размораживаем отрисовку интерфейса
        this.ResumeLayout();

        //скролим вслед за смещением кнопки
        _panel.ScrollControlIntoView(_buttonAdd);
    }
```

Comment: Я использую tablelayout и размножается внутри неё, плюс tablelayout находится в tabcontrol. И у всех элементов внутри tablelayout задан тип размера в процентах для адаптивности.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю в layout размер не меняется когда добавляешь, а внутри всё между собой в соотношении.